# Why are OLEDB / ODBC legacy technologies still used in PowerQuery?

Tags: sql-server, excel, odbc, office365, powerquery

I recently had an issue in Excel 2016, using Windows 10's native 32bit ODBC connections (DSN), to extract data from SQL views and tables, in SQL Server 2008.

For some reason, over the past few weeks (Oct 2019), certain SQL commands called directly from Excel to SQL Server, via ODBC were causing Excel to "crash", but more like freeze. I had to kill Excel via the Task Manager.

The views ran in under 2 seconds in SQL Server, but Excel took **forever** to load - sometimes over 5 to 20 minutes!

The frustrating thing was, these Excel templates worked fine before Oct 2019, and relatively fast (under 30seconds). Lately, something has changed because now some queries are causing Excel to freeze, with "Connecting to datasource", and no further activity.

I've converted the queries into *PowerQuery*, using direct Data to SQL Server connection. However, I've noticed that the M-code for this was still referring to ODBC.

> Source = Odbc.Query(...

And yes, the query still took over 20 minutes to finish!

The M script is as follows ('#' for privacy):

```
let
    ParamTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    wsFinal = if Text.From(ParamTable[ENTER VISIT]{0}) = null then "0" else Text.From(ParamTable[ENTER VISIT]{0}),
    Param = "'" & wsFinal & "'",
    Source = Odbc.Query("DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=####;DATABASE=####;", 
    "SELECT v.*
    FROM   vwEDImlRowCnt AS v
    WHERE  v.VisitID = " & Param)
in
    Source
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend constructing dynamic SQL like that. How was that code generated? I'd recommend trying to recreate it via the query editor GUI instead.

Comment: But it's standard SQL Server SQL. If it works in SQL Server, why wouldn't it work from the M editor?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just suggesting something to try.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I did use the wizard, and I've learnt the SQL is fine. You can put any SQL in the M string because it's passing over the command to SQL Server. The question is why does PowerQuery add that "ODBC" tag? Is it because all Windows connections to external servers, are via ODBC? There is no other technology?

Comment: That's weird. When I connect to a SQL Server it looks like `let Source = Sql.Databases("servername"){[Name="databasename"]}[Data]...`.

Comment: What version of ODBC and OLEDB have you got?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with sending an initial query to the server, as there are a lot of operations you can do that PQ won't fold (though this doesn't look like such a case). But yeah, you should be using the Sql.Database to connect, not Odbc.Query. Are you saying you selected From Database->SQL Server Database in the PQ menu and it did that?

Comment: @Wedge no. I made a mistake (answer below), but decided to keep the question here in case others fall for the same trap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "problem". It's not a problem. It's the way Excel just confuses things unnecessarily.

I found this happens when I've created a normal Excel query using "From Other Sources", via the data tab.

[image]

This generates by default a request to connect via **ODBC**.

However, when I changed the "connection" (still don't know why Excel calls queries **Connections** and SQL queries **Queries**) over to PowerQuery, it actually **keeps** the **ODBC** connection in the new PowerQuery's *M language*.

The solution for me, was not create a query "From Other" but from directly in the SQL Database, which is what I thought I had done.